# xml parsing in php issue in neseted loop

Tags: php, xml

I am facing a problem in parsing an XML file where first 3 elements of `<Innings>parsed(Innings id="1",Innings id="2",Innings id="3")` but   `<MatchDetail><PlayerDetail><SessionUpdates>` could not.
How can I solve it?
My [xml file is here](http://optasports.com/media/888415/crml-36474.xml).
Code is given below:

```
    <?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://optasports.com/media/888415/crml-36474.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");



foreach($xml as $news) {
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($news);


    /*Innings id="1" batting_team_id="3" bowling_team_id="2" declared="0" follow_on="0" forfeited="0" overnight_runs="0" 
    overnight_wickets="0"> */
     echo '<h2>Innings:</h2>';
    echo " Innings id:" .$news['id'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo " batting_team_id:".$news['batting_team_id'];

    echo " bowling_team_id:".$news['bowling_team_id'];

    echo " declared:".$news['declared'];

    echo " follow_on:".$news['follow_on'];

    echo " forfeited:".$news['forfeited'];

    echo " overnight_runs:".$news['overnight_runs'];

    echo " overnight_wickets:".$news['overnight_wickets'];

        echo "<br>";    

    //print_r($news->Bowlers);  

    echo '<h4>Batting</h4>';
    foreach($news->Batsmen as $Batsmen){
        /*Batsman id="3107" balls_faced="1" bowled_by="3065" caught_by="4456" day="1" dismissal_id="3" fours_scored="0" how_out="Caught Jos Buttler Bowled James Anderson" 
        minutes="3" non_strike="0" on_strike="0" order="2" runs_scored="0" sixes_scored="0" */
        foreach($Batsmen as $Batsman){
            echo " Batsmen id:" .$Batsman['id'];

            echo " balls_faced:".$Batsman['balls_faced'];

            echo " bowled_by:".$Batsman['bowled_by'];

            echo " caught_by:".$Batsman['caught_by'];       
            echo "day:".$Batsman['day'];    
            echo " dismissal_id:".$Batsman['dismissal_id']; 
            echo " fours_scored:".$Batsman['fours_scored']; 
            echo " how_out:".$Batsman['how_out'];   
            echo " minutes:".$Batsman['minutes'];
            echo " non_strike:".$Batsman['non_strike']; 
            echo " on_strike:".$Batsman['on_strike'];
            echo " order:".$Batsman['order'];
            echo " runs_scored:".$Batsman['runs_scored'];
            echo " sixes_scored:".$Batsman['sixes_scored'];             
            echo "<br>";            
        }               

    }   

    echo '<h4>Bowling</h4>';
    foreach($news->Bowlers as $bowlers){
/*<Bowler id="3065" balls_bowled="0" dot_balls="79" maidens_bowled="4" no_balls="0" non_strike="1" on_strike="0" order="1" overs_bowled="17" 
runs_conceded="51" wickets_taken="2" wides="0"/> */
            //echo"<pre>";          
            //print_r($bowlers);

        foreach($bowlers as $bowler){
                //print_r($bowler);
                echo "Bowler id:" .$bowler['id'];

            echo " balls_bowled:".$bowler['balls_bowled'];

            echo " dot_balls:".$bowler['dot_balls'];

            echo " maidens_bowled:".$bowler['maidens_bowled'];

            echo " no_balls:".$bowler['no_balls'];

            echo " non_strike:".$bowler['non_strike'];

            echo " order:".$bowler['order'];

            echo " overs_bowled:".$bowler['overs_bowled'];

            echo " runs_conceded:".$bowler['runs_conceded'];

            echo " wickets_taken:".$bowler['wickets_taken'];

            echo " wides:".$bowler['wides'];
            echo "<br>";                
            }                           
    }

    echo '<h4>Extra</h4>';
    foreach($news->Extras as $Extras){
     /*<Extras byes="6" leg_byes="1" no_balls="0" penalties="0" total_extras="7" wides="0"/>*/  
        echo " byes:".$Extras['byes'];
        echo " leg_byes:".$Extras['leg_byes'];
        echo " no_balls:".$Extras['no_balls'];
        echo " penalties:".$Extras['penalties'];
        echo " total_extras:".$Extras['total_extras'];
        echo " wides:".$Extras['wides'];
        echo "<br>";        
    }   
    echo '<h4>Fall of wicket</h4>';
    foreach($news->FallofWickets as $FallofWicket){
        /*<FallofWicket order="1" over_ball="0.4" player_id="3107" runs="3"/>   */
        //print_r($FallofWicket);
        foreach($FallofWicket as $Wicket){
        echo " order:".$Wicket['order'];
        echo " over_ball:".$Wicket['over_ball'];
        echo " player_id:".$Wicket['player_id'];
        echo " runs:".$Wicket['runs'];
        echo "<br>";        
        }
    }
    echo '<h4>Total</h4>';
    foreach($news->Total as $Total){
        /*<Total overs="61.1" runs_scored="148" wickets="10"/>*/    

        echo " overs:".$Total['overs'];
        echo " runs_scored:".$Total['runs_scored'];
        echo " wickets:".$Total['wickets']; 

    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, please add a valid but mini-version of that XML. The external link may vanish one day, then your question is incomprehensible. Please strip down your PHP code as well to the absolute minimum to clarify the problem. And please define exactly what is not working the way you want it to work. If you do this, you are going to get very valuable answers here on SO.

Comment: please tell me how can i get all data from child element(<Innings>,<MatchDetail>,<PlayerDetail>,<SessionUpdates>) from the xml file